# OnItemLongClickListener in gridview is not working

Tags: android, adapter, android-gridview, onlongclicklistener

In my project, I am enabling the movement of items in gridview(Like dragging or reordering) when Items LongCLick. For that i used code from [this](https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid) reference.

When i Long press the items in gridview , OnItemLongClickListener is not being called. In reference code, it works fine. But when i implement this in my code,its not working. so anyone please suggest me a better solution to correct this issue or else provide any code snippet to move a items in gridview.

Setting in Adapter :

```
assignmentGridView.setAdapter(new CheeseDynamicAdapter(getApplicationContext(),bulletines ,2));
```

OnItemLongClickListener:

```
assignmentGridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    assignmentGridView.startEditMode();
                    return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom adapter and inflate custom layout file then set this properties

```
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
  android:focusable="false"
```

for your all UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
assignmentGridView.setLongClickable(true);
```

Comment: i had run the code after including this but still no response